# Building an online journal

Tags: html, web, journal, web-platforms

I need to build an online journal managing system where people can start their own [personal/public] journals (like wordpress has blogs). Since it is a journal, the users should be able to assign editors, reviewers, etc.

I'm aware of Open Journal Systems but it doesn't allow anyone to launch their journal. Also, I've only a week of time.

Which platform would be best suited for such thing? I'm thinking PHP, but I'd love any other platform which can speed up the process.

Comment: Is this something you have to build yourself from the ground up? Are you allowed to use frameworks?

Comment: Yes, I'm allowed to use frameworks.

Comment: Take a look at CodeIgniter. It's fairly easy to wrap your head around and you can whip up a basic application very quickly. It's not specifically an online Jounal system, but there are code example which will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by Open Journal System not allowing anyone to launch their own journal?  The software can be downloaded freely (http://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs_download) and run on a LAMP server just as Wordpress is.  OJS has all of the necessary journal management requirements (editorial/reviewer roles, publication of documents for public consumption) built right in, and is extensible in many ways.